# Can not use built-in functions with importlib in python 3.7.9

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-importlib

I'm trying to use a function imported by importlib as a matplotlib formatter. And inside the function I can not get access to built-in functions. And I have no idea why. Can anyone help with it?

I'm running this code

```
formatterCode = '''
from builtins import *
def myFormatter(x, y):  
    return str(float(x))
'''

print(formatterCode,  file = open('formatter.py', 'w'))

import os, importlib
spec        = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('module.name', 'formatter.py')
formatters  = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(formatters)

import matplotlib, dill
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
myFormatter = matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(formatters.myFormatter)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(myFormatter)
ax.plot([1, 2], [1, 2])
with open('test.tmp', 'wb') as f:
    dill.dump(fig, f, recurse = False)

plt.close('all')

with open('test.tmp', 'rb') as f:
    figure = dill.load(f)

figure.savefig("test.png")
plt.close('all')
```

on

```
Python 3.7.9 (default, Feb 18 2021, 03:10:35)
[GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-12)] on linux
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
  File "formatter.py", line 4, in myFormatter
    return str(float(x))
NameError: name 'str' is not defined
```